# Javascript Random Image

Tags: javascript

Im doing a random image display as part of a lab and I cant get the third image to appear (scissors.png). Thats my javascript below..Help would be much appreciated!

```
var total = 0;
function Images(){
     var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
     var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)+1;

     /* Player one */

     if (x ==1)
         img1.src = 'rock.png';
     else if (x==2)
         img1.src = 'paper.png'; 
     else if (x==3)
         img1.src = 'scissors.png';

 }
```

Comment: try Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1

Comment: @vp_arth - I edited his code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm doing a random image display as part of a lab and I can't get the third image to appear (scissors.png).

That's because you're multiplying your random number by 2, and then flooring it, which gives you a range of 0-2 (inclusive); which isn't a problem (given zero-based arrays) but your `if`is expecting one-based array indexes.

Incidentally, I'd suggest:

```
var images = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

return images[rand] + '.png';
```

Leading to an implementation like so:

```js
function getImage() {
  var images = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);

  return images[rand] + '.png';
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(getImage());
});
```

```html
<button>Get an image</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1;
```

I'd also suggest you use: `if (x === 1)`.

Comment: `===`, for what? can Math.floor return not int?

Comment: It's just considered good practice in programming, or so I've heard. It reduces the chance of accidental evaluation.

Comment: Douglas Crockford describes == as the evil twins in Javascript The Good Parts, by O'Rielly.

Comment: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/excerpts/javascript-good-parts/bad-parts.html

Comment: And what, must we pray to O'Reilly rules? `===` still redundant while same types comparing.

Comment: I made a suggestion, in addition to my answer, that promotes good coding habits. If you don't agree with me that's fine. It's the one time when you're comparing types and overlook something, that'll get ya. I've found that debugging those is a nightmare. Perhaps you're an incredible programmer that doesn't have to take these safeguards. Mere mortals like me benefit from taking these precautions. Thanks for the input @vp_arth; I see your point about writing ultra sleek code.

Comment: I edit your answer now, just for downvote removing, sorry for this holywar.

Comment: Thanks @vp_arth. I'm glad there are people who are willing to promote healthy conversation and keep this community positive.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function Images(){
     var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3), // pick a random number: 0, 1 or 2
         results = [rock, paper, scissors]; // Array of names, ordered.

     // pick the right index from the array, so if the random number was '1', 
     // so the value at that index is used, which is "paper".
     document.getElementById('img1').src = results[rand] + '.png';
 }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: well they can compare the question's code to the answer's code and learn the difference. The code really explains itself, it's the very fundamentals of javascript, nothing fancy or tricky. I will add comments since you've asked but it's unneeded IMHO.

Comment: This is probably as self-commenting as self-commenting can get. That being said, the author could probably benefit from an explanation of what he did wrong (that is, his `random` is not going to ever return 3)

Comment: I now wrote comments guys, i hope everything will be crystal clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change your multiplier to 3.
Or even to variable, that equals number of possibility results.

`Math.random` return us `0 <= r < 1`.
Then multiplying, we can to get `0 <= r*n < n` float numbers.
`Math.floor` get us integers `0 <= k < n` or, that equals `0 <= k <= n-1`
You should to add 1 to this sequence, if you want to get `[1, n]`,
but `[0, n-1]` is the best for array index with length `n`.

Here example of implementation:

```
function action(images){
     document.getElementById('img1').src = 
                images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
} 

action([
  'rock.png',
  'scissors.png',
  'paper.png',
  'lizard.gif',
  'Spok.jpg'
]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I don't think that questions like `Here is my code, what's wrong?` are useful for future readers. But you are right, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Math.random() returns a float value between the range [0, 1) - meaning including 0 but up to 1 excluding 1.

So, the max value is 0.99 * 2 = 1.98 and incremented by 1 is 2.98. Floor value of that is 2.

Easiest solution would be just to multiply it by 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.random() ∈ [0,1)
⇒ Math.random() * 2 ∈ [0,2)
⇒ Math.floor(Math.random()*2) ∈ [0,1] ∩ ℤ = {0,1}
⇒ Math.floor(Math.random()*2) + 1 ∈ {1,2}
```

If you want a number of the set `{1,2,3}`, you should multiply by 3:

```
Math.random() ∈ [0,1)
⇒ Math.random() * 3 ∈ [0,3)
⇒ Math.floor(Math.random()*3) ∈ [0,2] ∩ ℤ = {0,1,2}
⇒ Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1 ∈ {1,2,3}
```

Comment: This answer won't be displayed well if your browser can't display unicode characters.